# Unable to have 100 factorial with C++ on output screen(displaying 0)

Tags: c++, integer, max, bit

Well I am stuck on this problem for quite a while:

**Question:**
You are asked to calculate factorials of some small positive integers.

---

**Input:**

An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of testcases, followed by t lines, each containing a single integer n, 1<=n<=100.

---

**Output:**

For each integer n given at input, display a line with the value of n!

```
//coded in c++
#include <bits/stdc++.h> //loadind up all the libraries at once.
using namespace std;

int main()
{   int T;
    scanf("%d", &T); 

//I am not doing "cin<<" cause "scanf" is faster than it

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        int N;
        scanf("%d",&N);
        long long int product = 1;
        while (N >0){
            product = product * N;
            N--;
        }
        printf("%lld\n",product);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to get 10!,20! but unable to get 100! (factorial)
so the extreme case doesn't satisfy. Please help me to get a good data type for my variable as 100! a factorial has over than 100 digits. It is displaying 0 when I input 100 on the terminal.

P.S - This problem is from CodeChef website (FCTRL2).

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` no, no, no.

Comment: `100!` is far too large to fit in a 64-bit value.

Comment: There isn't a built-in integer data type that will hold 100!  You will have to write a class to store such large numbers, or use someone else's class for the job.

Comment: Well I was thinking what if I use string in place of integer.

Comment: @vivekupadhyay Take a look at [factorial of big numbers with strings in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385101/factorial-of-big-numbers-with-strings-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I've added CodeChefs to my list of bad C++ websites (along with Geeks for Geeks, Udemy, Cplusplus).

Comment: @Eljay,could you tell me a good website to learn c++

Comment: For learning C++, I have not found any websites that are better than a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 64bit integer will overflow with 23!

Therefore you need to do it with digits and a vector.

This is a rather simple task. We can do it like we would do it on a piece of paper. We use a `std::vector` of digits to hold the number. Because the result will be already too big for an `unsigned long long` for 23!.

The answer will be exact.

With such an approach the calculation is simple. I do not even know what to explain further.

Please see the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Calculate n!   Enter n (max 10000): ";
    if (unsigned int input{}; (std::cin >> input) && (input <= 10000)) {

        // Here we store the resulting number as single digits
        std::vector<unsigned int> result(3000, 0);  // Magic number. Is big enough for 100000!
        result.back() = 1;                          // Start calculation with 1 (from right to left)

        // Multiply up to the given input value
        for (unsigned int count = 2; count <= input; count++)
        {
            unsigned int sum{}, remainder{};
            unsigned int i = result.size() - 1;     // Calculate from right to left
            while (i > 0)
            {
                // Simple multiplication like on a piece of paper
                sum = result[i] * count + remainder;
                result[i--] = sum % 10;
                remainder = sum / 10;
            }
        }
        // Show output. Supporess leading zeroes
        bool showZeros{ false };
        for (const unsigned int i : result) {
            if ((i != 0) || showZeros) {
                std::cout << i;
                showZeros = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Wrong input.";
}
```

Using a bigint library will be much faster.

---

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2.

Additionally compiled and tested with clang11.0 and gcc10.2

Language: C++17